# How to get url from parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

One of my parameters in the routing is actually an url.

```
router.get('/api/sitemap/:url', function(req, res) 
        {

            var  url = req.params.url;
            ...
        }
```

How do I allow this to go through when the :url is actually a link like "http://domain.com/file.xml".

I get a 404 error which I understand as it is not linking properly and cannot process as it errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does an example for the complete URL for this endpoint look like? Are you encoding the URL parameter properly? I guess not.

Comment: Note quite the issue. My url is http://localhost:3000/api/sitemap/domain.com/file.xml and it seems that the error is thrown regardless.

Comment: What if you try `http://localhost:3000/api/sitemap/domain.com%2Ffile.xml` instead? I guess if you get a 404 error, it means that the server cannot find a route for the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router returns 404 because it can't recognize the path.
You should either encode the url param as suggested in the comments, or slice it further, as:

`.get('/api/site/:domain/: file', cb)`

The trouble there is that if you also pass the protocol, you have to match even that.

Don't have a console to try now, but I think you might be able to pass a wildcard:

```
'/api/sitemap/*'
```

You would have to parse out the url on your own then, but it's simple:

```
var url = req.url.substr(14);
```

(Not sure if it's 13 or14 on the index there, counting on hands since I'm on my mobile :-)).